# I can not connect Google Cloud Messaging to Android client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a simple example to work with Google Cloud Messaging to Android. I have a php server that is to send a notification android client. I can not understand how the petroleum products in android. I found examples but can not start them. I tried gradle project creation. wrote dependence:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
```

and he found it. but the classes are not available from the library anyway.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
```

Android Studio not find and:

`GCMBaseIntentService` and `GCMConfig` not find too

I created a project ant. android sdk Extras->Google Play Services  and took away the library:

```
AndroidSDK\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libsgoogle-play-services.jar
```

and connect it. but the same error.

What am I doing wrong? tell me how to set up and connect to the android client Google Cloud Messaging?

Comment: I answered your question in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246293/how-to-connect-the-library-gcm-in-gradle/27265408#27265408)