# how to connect the library gcm in gradle?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I downloaded the example [link](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/)

ran it and it worked fine. but now I want to do it in the android studio. I try to connect the library:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71"
```

but the classes are not visible and the package too

```
 android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
```

how to connect the library GCM in gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You should install Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library in a [SDK Manager](http://clip.corp.mail.ru/clip/m0/1417589435-clip-146kb-JlRjLEnlLgn3.png) . After doing it Android Studio will be see all classes from gcm.jar.

Comment: Stop using jars, start using Gradle for dependency management. Spend time now, save time later.

Answer (score 0):

You need the gcm-server.jar. 
Add compile("com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2") in build.gradle as the following:

dependencies {
`compile("com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2")`
}